# Split a string using whitespace in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, tokenize

I need a tokenizer that given a string with arbitrary white-space among words will create an array of words without empty sub-strings.

For example, given a string:

```
" I dont know what you mean by glory Alice said."
```

I use:

```
str2.split(" ")
```

This also returns empty sub-strings:

```
["", "I", "dont", "know", "what", "you", "mean", "by", "glory", "", "Alice", "said."]
```

How to filter out empty strings from an array?

Answer (score 18):

You probably don't even need to filter, just split using this Regular Expression:

```
"   I dont know what you mean by glory Alice said.".split(/\b\s+/)
```

Comment: Off-topic: what mean `\b` in regex?

Comment: Matches a word boundary, such as a space, a newline character, punctuation character or end of string (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Might not be the perfect Regex but for that example it works.

Comment: @Mustafa yeah, I know. But it is just a curiosity.

Comment: I like the regex, but how to account for ", " (comma, space)

Answer (score 11):

```
 str.match(/\S+/g)
```

returns a list of non-space sequences `["I", "dont", "know", "what", "you", "mean", "by", "glory", "Alice", "said."]` (note that this includes the dot in "said.")

```
 str.match(/\w+/g)
```

returns a list of all words: `["I", "dont", "know", "what", "you", "mean", "by", "glory", "Alice", "said"]`

docs on [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Good answer. For others' reference, `/S+/` matches against groups of characters that are **not** whitespace, whereas `/w+/` matches groups of characters that **are** alphanumeric+underscore. That's why the period (`.`) character matches in one but not the other.

Answer (score 7):

You should trim the string before using split.

```
var str = " I dont know what you mean by glory Alice said."
var trimmed = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
trimmed = str.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend `.match`:

```
str.match(/\b\w+\b/g);
```

This matches words between word boundaries, so all spaces are not matched and thus not included in the resulting array.

Comment: This works even better:
>>> str2
"Humpty Dumpty smiled contemptuously Of course you dont—till I tell you I meant theres a nice knock-down argument for you! "

Using:

str3 = str2.match(/\b\w+\b/g);

Results in:

>>> str3
["Humpty", "Dumpty", "smiled", "contemptuously", "Of", "course", "you", "dont", "till", "I", "tell", "you", "I", "meant", "theres", "a", "nice", "knock", "down", "argument", "for", "you"]

So w+ matchs also "—"

Comment: @dokondr: What do you count as word characters? If it's everything except spaces, you may want to just use `[^ ]` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

see the `filter` method

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX13

Answer (score 0):

i think empty sub-string happen because there are multiple white-spaces you can use a replace() in a for loop to replace multiple white-spaces with a single white-space then split() to split the program using a single white space like this:

```js
// getting full program from div
var program = document.getElementById("ans").textContent;
//removing multiple spaces
var res = program.replace("  ", " ");
for (i = 0; i <= program.length; i++) {
  var res = res.replace("  ", " ");
}
// spliting each word using space as saperator
var result = res.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is all that we need:

```
str.trim().split(' ')
```